# How can I order table rows?

Tags: jquery, html-table

Currently, I'm developing a **website**. There I have a page where **categories** are listed (and can also be edited & deleted). These will be shown later in a **survey**. I want to add the possibility to **edit the order** of the categories

I encountered the following problem:

[image: Visualization of the problem]

I'm filling the table with **data** from my **database**. When querying, these are only **automatically arranged** according to the **ID** of the record.

I have already found examples on the internet where the rows of the table can be **moved** with **JavaScript**.

The script looked like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var fixHelper = function (e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function () {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return ui;
    };
    $("#sort tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper
    }).disableSelection();
</script>
```

This script works, but **only** on the **client side**.

#### What I need to know is..

..how to **read out** the new order of all rows and **update** that in my **database**, so it doesn't reset after refreshing the page.

*(I also came across the term `Circular List`, but I don't really understand how to use them)*

Comment: Your server side should be sending ordered data directly. P.S.: Nothing to do with C# or ASP.NET either.

Comment: how are you populating this HTML table from your database currently? That seems to be significant to your problem, but you haven't shown that. I'd expect you should order the query by the position field, so it shows in the correct order initially. Or are you asking how to send updated position info back to the server? Your question is really vague and unclear, unfortunately. Please edit it.

Comment: `the positions of the rows are stored in my database and I don't know how to get them via JavaScript` you return them to your frontend, manipulate those positions with JS, then save those positions back to the DB. But do not expect us to write the code for you, nor to hold your hand in implementing the functionality - `I searched a lot but found nothing` reads a lot like "I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas", and that isn't a mindset that will get you much assistance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time since I asked this question and was able to solve it, but I still wanted to write down my solution:

I simply added a new **column** to my database table named `order`. In the administration tab I added the opportunity to change that value via

```html
<input type="number">
```

If an administrator then creates a **new question** or edits an **existing one**, the new order is **always sent** with the **submission** and, in the event of a change, is also **adjusted in the database**

When the data for the table is retrieved, it is automatically sorted by the **order** and **no longer** by its ID.